# Need to login to a site before scraping

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, autologin

I written a PHP script that scrapes the results of search on a website (zillow.com). However the site hides parts of the results until the user logs into their site. When my scraper runs, it doesn't collect any of the login-required information. It only scrapes the information available to a user who is not logged in.

I've tried using cURL with no success. Here is what I've got so far:

```
                $username = trim($values["myemail@gmail.com"]);
                $password = trim($values["mypass123"]);                    

                //login form action url
                $url="http://www.zillow.com/user/account/services/Login.htm"; 
                $postinfo = "email=".$username."&password=".$password;

                $cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt";

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
                curl_exec($ch);

                //page with the content I want to grab
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/Alamance-County-NC/list/fore_lt/pmf,pf_pt/2117_rid/0-125000_price/0-478_mp/1970-_built/priced_sort/36.249851,-79.236667,35.843385,-79.542489_rect/1_p/");

                //do stuff with the info with DomDocument() etc
                $html = curl_exec($ch);

                // Insert scraping code here

                curl_close($ch);
```

The scraping script is collecting the information on the page, just not ALL of the information available to a logged-in user.

In the source code, under the login form tag, there is an input tag with type="hidden". Is this preventing the automated login for working correctly? If not, what changes do I need to make to my code to get to function properly?

I've searched several threads relating to this topic and have tried many of the suggested solutions to get the script to login automatically without any success.

Comment: Hope you read there TOS and got permission http://www.zillow.com/corp/Terms.htm  **note the** You agree otherwise not to reproduce, modify, distribute, display or otherwise provide access to, create derivative works from, decompile, disassemble or reverse engineer any portion of the Services.

Comment: The next sentence seems to indicate scraping is allowed as long as the source is given: "Notwithstanding the foregoing, the aggregate level data provided on the Zillow Local-Info Pages, and available at http://www.zillowblog.com ... research/, (the “Aggregate Data”) may be used for non-personal uses, e.g., real estate market analysis. You may display and distribute derivative works of the Aggregate Data (e.g., within a graph), so long as Zillow is cited as a source."

Comment: Regardless, I wasn't interested in a summary of Zillow's terms of use. I was ultimately able to get this to work using Python.

Comment: @Steve have you got it working ever using PHP ? I'm need of the similar lately

Comment: @Arif No, not in PHP. However, I got exactly what I wanted using Python. Specifically, the packages mechanize and beautiful soup were used successfully to scrape the website.

Answer (score -1):

simply use Python -selenium to login and lxml to scrape data

Comment: I'm pretty sure we're looking for a php solution here.